# How do I get the number of processes that have been created since the last boot on a Linux machine

Tags: linux, process, proc

How do I get the number of processes that have been created since the last boot on a Linux machine?

I want to get it from a C++ program. Which proc file stores it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be in `/proc/stat`:

```
The "processes" line gives the number  of processes and threads created, which
includes (but  is not limited  to) those  created by  calls to the  fork() and
clone() system calls.
```

See file `Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt` in your kernel source tree for more information about the contents of `/proc/stat`.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to never discount the Linux man pages. I am putting a link below, to the one for /proc.

[Proc man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

To add to the answer given by Sami Laine, According to the above linked page, `/proc/stat` has a common entry:

```
processes 86031
                     Number of forks since boot.
```

As a side note(slightly off subject), if you are looking to see this data on a SPECIFIC process, and not "in general", you should use, `/proc/[pid]/status` which:

```
Provides much of the information in /proc/[pid]/stat and
              /proc/[pid]/statm in a format that's easier for humans to
              parse.
```

Answer (score 1):

Fork count since last boot:

```
vmstat -f
```